# How to integrate spring and hibernate with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

I have installed eclipse with integrated glassfish server. now i don't know how to install hibernate and spring into eclipse. any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You don't need to install spring or hibernate in eclipse to use it!**

Spring and Hibernate are frameworks which can be used in applications. Eclipse is only the IDE to write the code.

If you want to have support in Eclipse to write Hibernate and Spring Configuration files, you need some eclipse plugins:

- Eclipse Dali JPA Tools wich are part of Eclipse WTP and part of the Eclipse Java EE package or [Hibernate Tools](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/tools.html)
- Spring IDE or Spring Tool Suite

*In general I recommend to use the [Spring Tool Suite](http://www.springsource.com/developer/sts), it is based on Eclipse (3.6.1 for STS 2.5.2) Java EE (so it contains the JPA tools) and contains the Spring IDE plugin and some other Spring related tools.*

BTW: STS contains a wizzard to create some simple Spring applications with just a few clicks.

Comment: i have installed spring tool suite. now how can i install hibernate support in that and also do need glass fish server to link with spring tool suite

Comment: @Name I hope I have written it clearly enough: *You don't need to install spring or hibernate in eclipse to use it!* - what do you understand by the term "hibernate support".  To install a Glasfish: Server Pannel/New-Server/Download additional server adapters/ ...

Comment: thanks for the answer...! I think what @Ralph mentioned is 'you don't need to install the hibernate library (plugins) into eclipse manually'. :D

Answer (score 1):

Install [Apache Maven](http://maven.apache.org/). Use [appfuse](http://appfuse.org/display/APF/AppFuse+QuickStart) to generate a Maven command, create a project and use Maven's

```
mvn install eclipse:eclipse
```

to create Eclipse project files and import the project to Eclipse:

**File >> Import >> General >> Existing Projects**

Comment: for what purpose maven is used for. is it required for building web app  and what is appfuse

Comment: From apache.maven.org: "Apache Maven is a software project management and comprehension tool. Based on the concept of a project object model (POM), Maven can manage a project's build, reporting and documentation from a central piece of information."

Comment: From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_maven "Maven is a software tool for project management and build automation. While primarily used for Java programming, it can also be used to build and manage projects written in C#, Ruby, Scala, and other languages. Maven serves a similar purpose as the Apache Ant tool, but it is based on different concepts and works in a profoundly different manner. Maven is hosted by the Apache Software Foundation, where it was formerly part of the Jakarta Project."

Comment: It is not required to use Maven to build a web app but it's going to help a lot, especially with the AppFuse. It is an application used to create skeleton applications with technologies of choice. Since you have already chosen Spring and Hibernate, there's just one more choice to be made -- web framework and your web app development can start.

Comment: soorry for that but i still not understood how mavem , appfuse are related to my question. i want to build web site using spring,hibernate, spring web mvc , mysql eclispe , glassfish. i just want to know how to bundle everything in eclispe so that i can start it. i am confused to make them together

Comment: You are in front of a blank slate. Lot of people have been in your position. One of them, author of AppFuse, Matt Raible has developed a helper to start with a ready made web app. Go on, try it. It's not going to cost you a dime.